# Find the complex potential for this system.

Tags: proof-verification, fluid-dynamics

A cylinder of radius $a$ has axis that passes through the origin perpendicular to the $x-y$ plane. A line vortex of circulation $\Gamma$ has axis passing through $x=b,y=0, (b>a)$ also perpendicular to the $x-y$ plane.

I'm struggling to find the complex potential for this system.

I know that the complex potential for a line vortex at the origin is $$w(z)=\frac{-i\Gamma}{2\pi}\ln(z)$$ with $v_{R}=0$ and $v_{\theta}=\frac{\Gamma}{(2\pi R)}$.

I tried to apply The Milne-Thomson's circle theorem to the problem, i.e

$$w(z)=f(z)+\overline{f\left(\frac{a^{2}}{\bar{z}}\right)}$$
But I'm unsure what $f(z)$ should be from the wording of the question, is it $f(z)=-\frac{i\Gamma}{2\pi}\ln(z)$?

Comment: Almost correct, you also need to take into account the centre of the line vortex at $z_0 = x_0 + iy_0 = b$. So $f(z)$ should be $-\dfrac{i\Gamma}{2\pi}\ln(z - b)$.

Comment: Oh okay thank you for some reason after trying again I thought it would be $+b$ inside the logarithm , is it negative because it’s $z-z_{0}$?

Comment: Yes! You should try to read Acheson to get yourself more comfortable with the general idea (: thought, Acheson doesn't have many examples in terms of finding complex potentials.

Comment: I will however my exam on fluid dynamics is in one hour it should be fine

Comment: Good luck!!!!!!

Comment: Thank you! Hopefully it goes well!